# Nesting custom tags in Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I have a Laravel / Vue app that I'm building and I've run into a bit of a snag. I have been able to successfully create individual stand-alone components, however when I try to nest a stand-alone component into another component, only the nested component shows up. A bit of code:

**CompanyLogo.vue**

```
<template>
    <figure class="company-logo" :style="{
    width: size,
    height: size,
    backgroundImage: `url(${src})`
  }"></figure>
</template>
```

**LogoUploader.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="logo-container">
        <company-logo size="65px" :src="`${company.logo.url}`"></company-logo>
    </div>
    <div class="logo-uploaded-details">
        <p>Last updated: {company.logo.last_updated}</p>
        <button class="file-browse-btn">Upload Image</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

What's happening is that when in **company.blade.php** I simply have

```
<logo-uploader></logo-uploader>
```

The app compiles and loads, however only the `CompanyLogo` shows up on the screen. The entire markup for the `logo-uploaded-details` section isn't rendered at all.

I have tried adding a `require` for the `CompanyLogo` component to the registration for the `LogoUploader` component, but that didn't work either.

If I split out the components they both show up. The issue is only once they're nested.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue instances and components *must* have a single root element. In your `LogoUploader` you have two root elements.

You need to wrap them in a root.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="logo-container">
        <company-logo size="65px" :src="`${company.logo.url}`"></company-logo>
    </div>
    <div class="logo-uploaded-details">
        <p>Last updated: {company.logo.last_updated}</p>
        <button class="file-browse-btn">Upload Image</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Oh wow. I cannot believe I didn't know that. All this time I was just lucky that the rest of my components had a single root element. Thanks a bunch, man!

Comment: @matcartmill I can't actually find the documentation for it, but once it's bitten you a couple times you remember :)